# How to parse by one line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am looking for a solution about how to get all of my `int` Parses within one line. At the moment when I start my program I have to enter day, month and year. It is all done line by line. I want a solution or method where this does all of my parsing within one line and within a format of "dd/MM/yyyy".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");

            int day;
            int month;
            int year;


            day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Date i = new Date(day, month, year);



            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", i.day, i.month, i.year);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Date
        {
            public int month; // 1-12
            public int day; // 1-31 depending on month
            int value = 1;

            public int year
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }


            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                this.day = day;
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;
            }

            public int GetYear()
            {
                return year;
            }

            public void SetYear()
            {
                if (value > 1900 && value <= 2020)
                    year = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", value, "out of bounds");
            }

            private int Month
            {
                get { return month; }
                set
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12)
                        month = value;
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month", value, "Month must be 1-12");
                }
            }

            public int GetDay()
            {
                return day;
            }

            public void SetDay()
            {
                int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                if (value > 0 && value <= days[month])
                    day = value;

                else if (month == 2 && value == 29 &&
                    year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
                    day = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("days", value, "day is out of range");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you writing a class for `Date` when there is already a built-in type `DateTime` that has everything your class does.  This looks like a classic "don't re-invent the wheel" case.

Comment: @roryap It is an exercise which I am wanting to do.

Comment: You tell the user to enter the date as "dd/MM/yyyy", but then use three `ReadLine()` calls... that is not going to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.Parse`/`TryParse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`/`TryParseExact`:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dt;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(line,"dd/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
if(validDate)
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongDateString()); // now correctly initialized
```

With this format also `DateTime.Parse`/`DateTime.TryParse` works:

```
validDate = DateTime.TryParse(line, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

I use `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` to prevent that your local date separator is used instead of `/`(in case it's different).

Once it is parsed to `DateTime` it's trivial to create your `Date` instance:

```
Date d = new Date(dt.Day, dt.Month, dt.Year);
```

Comment: I am not wanting to use the preset DateTime class but I am using my own "Date" class.

Comment: @MinalModi: i have edited my answer. `DateTime` has all you need, `DateTime.Day`, `DateTime.Month` and  `DateTime.Year`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse `dd/MM/yyyy` formatted string to int because it is **not** a valid string.

You need to parse it to [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) first and you can use it's properties to get it's day, month and year as a numbers.

For example;

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter date as dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int day = dt.Day;
int month = dt.Month;
int year = dt.Year;
```

Or you can use `TryParseExact` if you don't wanna throw exception if input is not `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

> I am not wanting to use the preset DateTime class but I am using my
>   own "Date" class

If so, after you parse it, you can create your `Date` class instance with `Date(int day, int month, int year)` constructor based on this dt value as;

```
Date myDt = new Date(dt.Day, dt.Month, dt.Year);
```

Comment: I am not wanting to use the preset DateTime class but I am using my own "Date" class.

Comment: @MinalModi Updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you do NOT want to use DateTime.(Try)Parse, you can add a parse method with a Regex in your Date class:

```
public static Date ParseFromString(string s)
  {
     //string s = "24/12/2015";
     Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d+)[\/](\d+)[\/](\d+)");
     Match m = r.Match(s);
     if (m.Success)
     {
        return new Date(m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3]);
     }
     else
     {
         // throw exception
     }
  }
```